# ORM for non-destructive system?

Tags: orm, immutability

I don't know if there is a specific name for this, but I am designing an application backed by a database in which rows need to be immutable (not sure if that term applies here, but it is the closest to describing what I need).  That is, instead of changing the data stored in a row, a new row would be inserted with the same `id` but a different primary key.  There would be some metadata stored with row that would indicate which is the most current row for that `id`, and whether the record with that `id` has been "deleted".  I would like to use an ORM in which I could use normal `insert`, `update`, `delete` statements, but would do all that in the background.  Since I don't know what terminology to use, I am having a hard time finding a solution using the great, all-knowing Google.  Does an ORM like this exist, or would I have to build one / modify an existing one?  Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use any ORM that supports stored procedures, then write sprocs to perform the updates.

Answer (score 1):

What you might be looking for is a temporal database pattern whereby saving each item creates a new version. The idea behind temporal databases is that you can essentally query the data as it was at a given date.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might be asolution?

http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

The terminology for what your looking for is generally called Copy-on-write.

Ironically many databases like Postgresql (MVCC) and SqlServer (Snapshot) do some form of **COW** but for performance and ACID reasons.

From what I gather your probably looking for version control characteristics and while I do not know of any ORM or RDBMS that supports such behavior there are many content repositories that do. An example would be a JCR implementation (JSR 170) such as [**JackRabbit**](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/).

Otherwise I recommend you look how Wiki software works that uses an RDBMS (generally two columns indices with an id and version column).